# Bluetooth Networks do not permanently delete.. Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, kubuntu, network-manager, bluetooth

I'm running KUbuntu 18.04, and I have two Bluetooth network configurations in Network Manager that, once deleted in Network Manager, keep coming back after a reboot. They both are bluetooth connections to an old phone I no longer have and my new phone. The two entries in Network Manager are distinguished from each other by each phones MAC address in the Network Managers "Networks" popup. I can go into the Network Manager's "Edit Your Network Connections" and rightclick on each of the bluetooth connections and click "delete" and the network disappears, but upon reboot, there it is again.. I've tried deleting BOTH, even though I'd probably have a use for the one connecting to my current phone, but either way, delete one or delete both, they're both back upon reboot. What's the fix here??

Comment: Look in *System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Desktop Session > On Login*. Do you have *Restore Previous Session* enabled? If so, turn that off and choose *Start with an empty session*.

Comment: No, thats one KDE feature I do not care for, that being "restore previous session" and when I set up a new machine for me, thats one of the first things I turn OFF. I checked to be it hadn't gotten turned on by mistake and found it was set to "start with an empty session"...